# Combobox-Datatemplate & Selection TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a combobox which has 2 items. Each item is an objet deriving from a common interface. There is a DisplayText property on each object. Each object is templated so as to have a different visual. Everything works fine, except while selecting one of those objects, the visual is getting displayed in the combobox textbox. I want it to display the SelectedText property of the selected object in the textbox and the DisplayText inside the item template. How do I specify my binding for that please?

Here is my code:

```
public interface IMyDate
    {
        string DisplayText { get; }
        string SelectedText { get; }
    }

    public class TodayMinus1 : IMyDate
    {
        public string DisplayText { get { return "Yesterday"; } }
        public string SelectedText{get { return DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1).ToString(); }}
    }

    public class Today : IMyDate
    {
        public string DisplayText { get { return "TODAY"; } }
        public string SelectedText { get { return DateTime.Today.ToString(); } }
    }

    public class MyMainViewModel
    {
        public MyMainViewModel()
        {
            MyDates = new List<IMyDate>() {new Today(), new TodayMinus1()};
        }

        public List<IMyDate> MyDates { get; set; }
        public IMyDate SelectedDate { get; set; }
    }

<ComboBox MaxHeight="26" VerticalAlignment="Center"  x:Name="contextDropdown" ItemsSource="{Binding MyDates}"                                                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedDate}"  Grid.Column="1" Width="150" Margin="5">
 <ComboBox.Resources>
  <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:TodayMinus1}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayText}"/>
  </DataTemplate>
  <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Today}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayText}"/>
  </DataTemplate>
 </ComboBox.Resources>
</ComboBox>
```

Please note that this is an oversimplified example and I have implemented INPC for all my objects.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<ComboBox MaxHeight="26" VerticalAlignment="Center"  x:Name="contextDropdown" ItemsSource="{Binding MyDates}"                                                
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedDate}"  Grid.Column="1" Width="150" Margin="5">
    <ComboBox.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:TodayMinus1}">              
            <TextBlock>
                <TextBlock.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                        <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding DisplayText}" />
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ComboBoxItem}}" Value="{x:Null}">
                                <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding SelectedText}" />
                            </DataTrigger>                                 
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </TextBlock.Style>
            </TextBlock>                  
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Today}">
            <TextBlock>
                <TextBlock.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                        <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding DisplayText}" />
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ComboBoxItem}}" Value="{x:Null}">
                                <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding SelectedText}" />
                            </DataTrigger>                                 
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </TextBlock.Style>
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.Resources>
</ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

Added a DataTrigger inside the DataTemplate to achieve your requirement. Try this.

```
  <ComboBox  MaxHeight="26" VerticalAlignment="Center"  x:Name="contextDropdown" ItemsSource="{Binding MyDates}"                                                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedDate}"  Grid.Column="1" Width="150" Margin="5">
        <ComboBox.Resources>        
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:TodayMinus1}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayText}" x:Name="DisplayBox"/>
                <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,ComboBoxItem,1}}" Value="{x:Null}">
                        <Setter TargetName="DisplayBox" Property="Text" Value="{Binding SelectedText}"/>             
                    </DataTrigger>
                </DataTemplate.Triggers>
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Today}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayText}" x:Name="DisplayBox"/>
                <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,ComboBoxItem,1}}" Value="{x:Null}">
                        <Setter TargetName="DisplayBox" Property="Text" Value="{Binding SelectedText}"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </DataTemplate.Triggers>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.Resources>
    </ComboBox>
```